# while opening Android studio 3.1.3 it is showing sdk missing

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-studio, error-handling

I download android studio from its website.

After downloading it is showing missing Software development kit and i search on net their is no Software development kit file.

Comment: google is your best friend in this case

Comment: You can download the android software development kits (SDK) directly from within Android Studio, it's appropriately named [SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager). There should also be a link right next to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Just when the android studio starts go to the bottom right and select configure choose sdk manager and from there you can download missing sdk.